# How to put the content of all elements with a certain class in a variable with Jquery

Tags: jquery

Working with Jquery, I want to put the content of all elements with a specific class into a variable. Here's an example:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar"><p>First set of text</p></div>
    <div class="bar"><p>Second set of text</p></div>
    <div class="bar"><p>Third set of text</p></div>
    <div class="bar"><p>N set of text</p></div>
</div>
```

I would like to put the content of all div elements with the class "bar" into a variable named "full". I have tried the following code but that obviously only grabs the first div.

```
var full = $( ".bar" ).html();
```

I want the content of my string variable to be

```
"<p>First set of text</p><p>Second set of text</p><p>Third set of text</p><p>N set of text</p>"
```

If have tried looking on the internet but couldn't find an answer. I was thinking about using the .each method but my few tries didn't work out very well. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were right to want to use `.each()`:

```
var full = '';
$('.bar').each(function () {
    full += $.trim($(this).html());
})
console.log(full);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5ULBk/)**

Comment: Thank you very much, that principle worked perfectly in my working context. I will analyse this function to understand it a bit more some day, but for now I'll just take it as a gift! :)

Comment: If you need this chunk of code explained let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map()` as follows:

```
var full = $( ".bar" ).map(function(){ return this.innerHTML; }).get().join('');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/X2azw/)

In the above line please note that `this.innerHTML` is JS equivalent of jQuery's `$(this).html()`, meaning you could as well use `$(this).html()`.

Comment: Thanks, that solution seems to work perfectly in jsfiddle, altough I have used j08691's solution. Thanks very much!